# How to use Excel Builder (.js)

Tags: javascript, excel

I want to use JavaScript to dynamically create Excel documents.  The [Excel Builder(.js)](http://excelbuilderjs.com) package seems great.  It has a lot of features and even claims to have support for formula.

However, the demo code included in the download does not work.  The demo produces a file called "sample.xlsx", but this file cannot be opened by Excel.  I have tried the code on Windows 7/Chrome/Office 2010 and OSX/Chrome/Office 2011 with the same errors.

People can apparently use this, but I cannot get past the first step.

Comment: you can open a file with just an html table in excel if you rename .html to .xls. if you want formulas with that, just start the table cell content with "=", just like the formula view in excel. worked last time i tried. copying and pasting a table with formulas works for sure, i've done that recently...

Comment: @dandavis, thanks for the tip.  I'd like to get this library working, but it's good to know that this is a possible backup plan.

Answer (score 0):

How are you running the demo? If you simply open the demo/demo.html file on a browser, it will throw errors for several dependencies hosted on CDNs and will generate a broken xlsx. You can check the errors on your browser's console and open the xlsx file on a text editor to see that it's content is actually the same of the demo.html file.

To run the demo you need to run an local web server. I recommend [mongoose](https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) for windows and [this python script](http://osxdaily.com/2010/05/07/create-an-instant-web-server-via-terminal-command-line/) for OSX.